# android get URL path

Tags: java, android, url

I've got a string:

```
public://imageifarm/3600.jpg
```

How can I extract the

```
imageifarm/3600.jpg
```

Part out using android?

What I've tried so far:

```
URL drupalQuestionNodeImageURI = new URL("public://imageifarm/3600.jpg");
Log.d("TAG", drupalQuestionNodeImageURI.getPath());
```

but it throws this exception:

```
09-16 17:24:39.992: W/System.err(3763): java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: public
```

How can I solve this?

I know I can use regular expressions but that seems to defeat the purpose of URL(URI) in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use android.net.Uri

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse(public://imageifarm/3600.jpg);    
String extract = mUri.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
```

Comment: it returns `//imageifarm/3600.jpg`, should i manually remove the `//` or is there a Uri function for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use java.net.URI, not java.net.URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want have to use URL class (when you image sits on Internet) you have to provide valid URL (that begins from valid URL prefix, like http://, https:// etc). In you case you should use Uri class. Uri object can point on files in your local file system. For example:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("public://imageifarm/3600.jpg"));
```